# What do SELECT 1 and SELECT COUNT(1) do in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

So I just had an interview today for a java developer position, and they asked me this question

Can you tell the difference for

```
SELECT 1 FROM table
SELECT count(1) FROM table
SELECT count(*) FROM table
```

I looked up on stack overflow but couldn't find a satisfactory answer. I have been a Java developer with knowledge on SQL for a couple years, but have never had to use unfamiliar statements like Select 1 or select count(1)

Also this is the entire question. i.e, these queries are not part of any bigger query.

Could you please help me get an answer for this?

Comment: `count(*)` and `count(1)` are doing **exactly** the same thing.

Comment: As a side note: these are really terrible interview questions. Don't see what purpose they serve, especially if one is applying for a Java developer position.

Answer (score 8):

```
SELECT 1 FROM table
```

Will return `1` for as many times as there are records in `table`.

```
SELECT count(1) FROM table
```

Will return the count of all records in `table`.

```
SELECT count(*) FROM table
```

Same as above.

<s>`*` is used by Oracle as a hint (not technically a hint, but something similar) so it allows it to pick the best index to compute the count. That's the main difference with `select count(1)...`
Analogically, this is the same idea behind `WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ...)` versus `WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM ...)`</s> This statement is [no longer relevant](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::NO::P11_QUESTION_ID:1156159920245) to modern Oracle RDBMS engines.

Comment: There is no difference in operation or output between COUNT(*) and COUNT(any other constant). They are identical.

Comment: For completeness COUNT(1) is an example of COUNT(expression) which counts rows where the expression is non null. There is a variation  COUNT(DISTINCT expression) which does what it implies.

Comment: Oracle will not choose a  different index for `count(*)` vs `count(1)` those two expressions are doing **exactly** the same thing and neither is faster then the other.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thank you, I realize I was outdated.